# Can't set DateSelector to 31st of any month. Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When setting the date of birth to october 31st for a new student on my website and saving the information I get this error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

When pressing backspace on the website, the month only has 28 days.  Here is the dateselector code:

```html
 <td>
    <asp:Label ID="dateOfBirthLabel" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, DateOfBirth %>" />
</td>
<td style="width: 350px; float: left;">
    
    <uc:DateSelector runat="server" ID="ucDateSelector" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth") %>' />
</td>
```

Comment: Obvious question, what date are you trying to enter?

Comment: Change the month before the day.

Comment: I'm entering october 31st

Comment: I remember getting this error when a user enters some script tags into an input and submits the form. Try setting the EnableEventValidation to false (temporarily) then debug the postback and see what values are coming through?
Is uc:DateSelector a custom control of yours? Perhaps there's a bug in there.
Try using 3 asp:DropDowns (for DD, MM, YYYY)  instead?